# How to mount a Sails.js app as express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I would like to use Sails within a larger express based app. Most node.js MVC frameworks I have worked with you can mount as express middleware. Is this possible with Sails?

I want to do something like:

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express();

var mySailsApp = require('./mysailsapp');

app.use(mySailsApp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are some [active efforts](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/1522) to develop systems that would let Sails be more modularized, there's no way to use a Sails app as Express middleware.  Sails works on top of Express, but not the other way around.  However, you can use custom Express middleware with Sails--see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939832/adding-custom-express-middleware-like-jquery-file-upload-to-sails-js/21946577#21946577) for an example.