# How do I authenticate access to assets folder in sails.js

Tags: static, sails.js, assets, passport.js

I am already using passport to authenticate users. I added kibana 3 to the assets folder and want users to access it only if they are authenticated. how do i do this ?

Answer (score 8):

The **assets** folder is intended for publicly-available files, like your images and Javascripts.  If you want to protect those files, you can either override the default `www` middleware in Sails, which activates the Express static handler to servet those files (see details on overriding default middleware in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939832/adding-custom-express-middleware-like-jquery-file-upload-to-sails-js/21946577?noredirect=1#comment37406699_21946577)), or save the files you want to protect in a different location and use a controller action to serve them (probably the more reasonable option).

So, you could save the files in **protected_files**, and add a route like this to **config/routes.js**:

```
'/protected/:file': 'ProtectedFileController.download'
```

then in **controllers/ProtectedFileController**:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    download: function(req, res) {

        // Get the URL of the file to download
        var file = req.param('file');

        // Get the file path of the file on disk
        var filePath = path.resolve(sails.config.appPath, "protected_files", file);

        // Should check that it exists here, but for demo purposes, assume it does
        // and just pipe a read stream to the response.
        fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);

    }


};
```

Then protect that controller / action using a policy like you would with any other area that needs authentication.

Comment: Instead of doing `fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);` ,you can also use the [standard express method](http://expressjs.com/it/api.html#res.download) to dowload files.(available in sails for HTTP transport protocol only)