# sails.js: download file in assets directory

Tags: download, sails.js, assets

I create a .xls file in assets/xls directory :

```
fs.writeFileSync('./assets/xls/data.xls', xls, 'binary');
```

And I want to download this file :

To get the file url :

```
var downloadLink = req.headers.host+'/xls/data.xls';
```

I do not understant why I have a 404 error on this url :
localhost:1337/xls/data.xls

Comment: and the file is present under ./assets/xls/ ?

Comment: Yes the file is present

Comment: Sorry it's present under your project folder or under your web deploy folder .tmp/public/xls/ ? Cause if it's only under your project folder it's normal to have 404

Comment: I restart my server several times. I think it's a bug because after 10 tries my files is finallly in .temp directory.

Comment: I think you have to do fs.writeFileSync(sails.config.appPath + "/public/xls/data.xls", xls, 'binary'); to write it directly under temp folder

Comment: yes, files are not loaded directly from assets, they are loaded from the tmp folder

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the recommended practice for storing generated or user-uploaded files.  The `assets` folder is only intended for your site's front-end assets.

If you want to provide download links in your app, you're encouraged to save them in a separate location and add a controller action that streams the requested file to the client.  This allows you to add policies to protect those files, and avoids issues source control and with Grunt.  See [How do I authenticate access to assets folder in sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235653/how-do-i-authenticate-access-to-assets-folder-in-sails-js/24247649#24247649) for an example of such a controller action.